# Remove Jumbotron text underline in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added some headers and text to my jumbotron and any time I mouse over the jumbotron, the text underlines like it's a link (it's not). Here's my html:

```
<div class ="jumbotron">

    <div class = "container">
        <center><img src = "img/VVlogoFull.png" width = 60%>
            <h2>Welcome - Bienvenidos</h2>
        <p>an online repository of archaeological ceramics</p>
        <p>un repositorio en línea de cerámicas arqueológicas</p>
        <a href = "data.html" class="btn btn-accent">Database</a>
        <a href = "datos.html" class="btn btn-accent">Base de datos</a></center>
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm using the standard Bootstrap css.

Could you please suggest html changes or changes I could add to a style.css file so that this text doesn't underline when hovering over the jumbotron? I've already tried adding this to my style sheet:

```
.jumbotron h2{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and this within the html

```
<h2 style = "text-decoration : none">
```

all to no avail. Other suggestions?

Comment: Use your browser’s developer tools to find out where that underline comes from in the first place – then it should be easy to figure out what selector you need to use to overwrite it.

Comment: The code you've provided isn't enough to duplicate your issue. If I put this code in a page and use Bootstrap's CSS, no underline occurs when mousing over, not even for the links. Your question's code needs to reproduce the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: It may be the problem with your code. There may be some tags that is not closed or there may be some `"` to be closed .Double check your code. Or please paste the full code here.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know why, because I certainly didn't type it that way, but when I used the inspector in chrome it displayed my code as:

```
<a> <center><img src = "img/VVlogoFull.png" width = 60%>
    <h2>Welcome - Bienvenidos</h2>
<p>an online repository of archaeological ceramics</p>
<p>un repositorio en línea de cerámicas arqueológicas</p></a>
```

I fixed it by changing the code in my text editor to this:

```
<a style = "text-decoration: none"> <center><img src = "img/VVlogoFull.png" width = 60%>
        <h2>Welcome - Bienvenidos</h2>
    <p>an online repository of archaeological ceramics</p>
    <p>un repositorio en línea de cerámicas arqueológicas</p></a>
```

phantom code?